# How to set Bernoulli distribution parameters in pymc3

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc, pymc3

I have a model described in pymc3 using the following:

```
from pymc3 import * 
basic_model = Model()

with basic_model:
    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    alpha = Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=10)
    beta = Normal('beta', mu=0, sd=10, shape=18)
    sigma = HalfNormal('sigma', sd=1)

    # Expected value of outcome
    mu = alpha + beta[0]*X1 + beta[1]*X2 + beta[2]*X3

    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    Y_obs = Normal('Y_obs', mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=Y)
```

However, my `Y`s are not normally distributed but are binary (so, Bernoulli, I think). I can't figure out how to change the `Normal` distrubtion of Y to `Bernoulli` though because I can't figure out what the params would be of `Y_obs` in that case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are looking for is [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression). Here you use the logistic function to convert the output of your linear model to a probability.

In your example this could be specified as follows:

```
import pyMc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as T
basic_model = pm.Model()

def logistic(l):
    return 1 / (1 + T.exp(-l))

with basic_model:
    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=10)
    beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, sd=10, shape=18)

    # Expected value of outcome
    mu = alpha + beta[0]*X1 + beta[1]*X2 + beta[2]*X3

    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    Y_obs = pm.Bernoulli('Y_obs', p=logistic(mu), observed=Y)
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense (though I do know about logistic regression but I couldn't see how to model that in bayesian way). I'm giving your changes a try right now and will post here how it goes.

Comment: Well, it works but I get "exact" values for all `beta`s with standard deviation of `0.00` for all of them! I'm not even sure what question to ask here in order to proceed but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong :(  ... (My objective is simply to get some insight into my data -- purely exploratory)

Comment: Sounds like the sampler has difficulties accepting new points to sample. Which sampler do you use and how do you set the starting point? [Here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/examples/logistic.py) is an example of logistic regression with pymc3 which you could try.

Comment: That was a great pointer. I had gone to that github folder but missed the `logistic.py` file.  That helped a lot. I'm now training well with a basic `find_map` starting point and the NUTS sampler.

Comment: It may also be helpful to include random error in the log-odds (what you're calling `mu` here), by adding normally-distributed noise: ```eps = pm.Normal('eps', mu=0, sd=0.2); mu = alpha + beta[0]*X1 + beta[1]*X2 + beta[2]*X3 + eps```

Comment: Also worth noting that PyMC3 (and other probabilistic packages like Stan or Pyro/Numpyro) offer parameterization of a Bernoulli random variable using logits, so you could skip the logistic here and use `Y_obs = pm.Bernoulli('Y_obs', logit_p=mu, observed=Y)`. According to the Stan documentation, this logit parameterization of the Bernoulli distribution is more numerically stable...